# DELETE Call returns 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: android, node.js, heroku, kotlin

I have written an API call in nodejs where a user can delete his account:

```
router.delete('/deleteAccount', checkAccessToken, (req, res, next) => {


User.find({ username: req.tokenData.username })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if (user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Username does not exist'
            });
        }

                User.deleteOne({ username: req.tokenData.username }, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                });
                UserSprint.deleteMany({ username: req.tokenData.username }, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                });

                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Successfully deleted"
                });

    });

});
```

This call works perfectly fine when tested with Postman and locally, but after deploying the API to my Heroku Instance the call returns `415 Unsupported Media Type`

My call in Android:

```
@DELETE("user/deleteAccount")
fun deleteAccount(@Header(value = "authorization") authorization: String): Observable<Response<String>>
```

This is how I build my request

```
 val request = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf8")
                .header("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
                .method(original.method, original.body)
                .build()
```

Comment: Try changing the Content-Type header to `application/json;charset=utf-8`

Comment: @tbking thanks a lot this actually solved my problem!

Comment: I'm glad it heped you. I've posted an answer. Can you accept it and resolve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charset defined in Content-Type is not right. [Here's the list of all valid charset values.](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)

For UTF-8, change the header to: `application/json;charset=utf-8`.